# NSImageView Performance

Tags: objective-c, image, calayer, nsview, nsimageview

I have a very simple Mac Application; the best way to think of it is a master/detail view. Once an item is chosen on the left-hand side, information appears on the right pane, along with an image (can be various sizes/formats/resolutions due to the source). The user can very quickly select items on the left, and while the detail text on the right-hand pane appears quickly, we notice an immediate lag or plain failure to display the image on the right. Even the largest of images is a few MB, and typically less than 1024x1024 pixels. If the user moves slowly, everything is kosher...but if you go quick, it will hiccup...lag behind a few selections, or not display at all.

I've attempted solutions using nsviews' setNeedsDisplay, and alternatively using Core Animation layers, but nothing seems to do the trick. Is there a guide or set of tutorials on performant image display routines?

Targeting 10.6+

Comment: It's hard to guess without your code. But I'd recommend using Instruments with the time profiler to find where the culprit is.

Comment: If it turns out that NSImageView itself is the problem try to load thumbnails. IKImageView is also an option since you can give it a CGImageSourceRef.